# Parse html with Zend Dom

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am using Zend Dom component to parse some Html blocks, but i have problems extracting the a,b,c,d,e,f data from the following block:

```
 <div id="center">      
   <form action="" method="get">
     <table>
        <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                 <td></td>
            </tr>
         </table>
    </form> 
<table>     
  <tr>
    <td align="center"><b>a</b></td>
    <td align="left"><b>b</b>
         <br />c
         <br />d
    </td>
    <td align="left"><b>e<br />
            f<br />
            g
            </b>
            </td>
    </tr> <!-- this block repeats 10 times with other values instead of a,b,c...-->

</table>
</div>
```

Code:

```
  $client = new Zend_Http_Client();
  $client->setUri('http://example.com');                 
  $response = $client->request(); 
  $html = $response->getBody(); // the Html is the example above
  $dom = new Zend_Dom_Query($html);
  $results = $dom->query('#center table tr td');
```

Comment: please clarify what is not working and what output you expect to get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that what you're looking for?

```
    $dom = new Zend_Dom_Query ($code);
    $results = $dom->query ('#center table tr td');
    foreach ($results as $r)
    {
        echo '<p>', $r->textContent, '</p>';
    }
```

Comment: In current Zend2 versions:
$dom = new \Zend\Dom\Query($response->getContent());
$message = $dom->queryXPath('b');